# Constant LARAVEL_START already defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Every routes working fine when I run the app using `php artisan serve`, but when I am trying to run this on nginx , All routes were working fine except `/json.json`. Its shows below error.

```
Constant LARAVEL_START already defined
```

Here is the routes.php

```
<?php



Route::get('/', function()
{
        return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('json.json', 'HomeController@temp');
Route::post('anotheroute', 'HomeController@p');


});
```

and HomeController.php

```
<?php

include 'index.php' ;
class HomeController extends BaseController {



        public function showWelcome()
        {
                return View::make('hello');
        }
        public function temp()
        {
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
                $x = select_artist_by_name();
                return Response::json(array_keys($x));
        }
```

Comment: Do the error logs provide you with a line number or stacktrace to look back through?

Comment: why do you `include 'index.php'` in controller ?

Comment: LOG.error: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Constant LARAVEL_START already defined' in /var/www/music/bootstrap/autoload.php:3  @Wader

Comment: @egig some function definition

Comment: Whats in index.php? If you need to access some functions I personally create app/helpers.php and include that at the bottom of app/start/global.php.

Comment: Thanks @Wader . Now the problem is solved .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case i had this error on an external file of my laravel project.

so i checked if constant was defined before including files :

```
if (!defined('LARAVEL_START')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
    );
}
```